# Using gsub adding new column in a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Sorry for a very basic question, solution must be very simple but I'm not able to find it.

Trying to use gsub adding a new column in a data.table, I got the warning 
"*argument 'replacement' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used*", and all data.table rows have, in the new column, the value of the first row.

Here is a semplified case:

```
dt <- data.table(v1=c(1,2,3) , v2=c("axb","cxxd","exfxgx"))  
dt[ , v3:=gsub("x",v1,v2)]
```

The new column v3 contains a string with "1" instead of "x" in all the rows.

Using other functions, e.g.

```
dt[ , v3:=paste(v1,v2)]
```

works as expected.

I'm using Rstudio v.0.98.1103 , R v.3.1.2, data.table v.1.9.4

Comment: `gsub` is not vectorized in the replacement, so that's what the warning is telling you.

Comment: Another option would be `myFunc <- function(x, y) gsub("x", x, y) ; dt[ , v3 := mapply(myFunc, v1, v2)] `. Also, re my edit, when you are using the `:=` operator, it is updating the data in place, so no need to reassign it again using `dt <- dt`. Take a look [here](https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reference-semantics.html) for more information.

Comment: @DavidArenburg : thank you for your comment, I'm used to reassign data table even if the update is in place because I find very annoying, during execution, to see in the console  all the heads/tails of updated data tables (it's more difficult to notice errors/warnings). Maybe there are more clever ways to avoid it...

Answer (score 13):

```
dt[, v3 := gsub("x", v1, v2), by = v1]
```

Comment: Clever. By could also be `1:nrow(dt)` I guess. +1

Comment: @AnandaMahto I guess that's less efficient if there are any repeated values (unlike in the OP), for example, `dt <- data.table(v1=c(1L,1:3),v2=paste0(c("a",letters[1:3]),"x"))`

Comment: @AnandaMahto: thank you, I prefer your 'by' because 'by=v1' works fine, but gives the same warning I mentioned ("argument 'replacement' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used")

Comment: That's strange, I don't get any warnings when I do `by=v1`

Comment: @QuinnWeber - I got it: with my real data, v1 has no unique values. 
To avoid the warning, 'by' must fetch 1 row at time (so I think that, for performance purposes, it's best to use functions with vectorized arguments, like suggested in the other answer)

Answer (score 6):

The easiest approach would be to use a string processing package that has vectorized arguments, like `stringi`:

```
library(stringi)
dt[, v3 := stri_replace_all_fixed(v2, "x", v1)][]
#    v1     v2     v3
# 1:  1    axb    a1b
# 2:  2   cxxd   c22d
# 3:  3 exfxgx e3f3g3
```

---

Alternatively, you can make your own "vectorized" version of `gsub` by using the `Vectorize` function:

```
vGsub <- Vectorize(gsub, vectorize.args = c("replacement", "x"))
dt[, v3 := vGsub("x", v1, v2)][]
#    v1     v2     v3
# 1:  1    axb    a1b
# 2:  2   cxxd   c22d
# 3:  3 exfxgx e3f3g3
```

Comment: the latest stringr package is now powered by stringi. you can do library(stringr)
dt[ , v3:=str_replace(v2,"x",v1)]